# JDBC. Не создается driver = new FabricMySQLDriver(); - Java SE

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Привет всем.
Не получается создать Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver(); Пишет cannot resolve symbol FabricMySQLDriver.

Делаю пример по видеоурокам и там импортируется com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver - у меня такая штука импортироваться не хочет.

Подключено: Maven: mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что в 6.0.3 FabricMySQLDriver не определён и поэтому "cannot resolve symbol FabricMySQLDriver". Попробуйте в pom.xml заменить зависимость  на более раннюю версию, та что используется в вашем уроке или

```
<dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>mysql</groupId>
               <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
               <version>5.1.31</version>
           </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло) Не подскажете, а по-другому эта проблема решается? Должна же быть альтернатива в новой версии

Comment: @Анна из [справки](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/ch04s03s01s06.html): "Removed FabricMySQLDriver. Instead of using a separate driver, you can now obtain a connection that uses Fabric just by using the jdbc:mysql:fabric:// scheme."

Comment: @Анна http://pastebin.com/rwgPsfgW вам нужно использовать url в таком виде как написано в urlfixed и не нужно явно создавать Driver http://pastebin.com/rwgPsfgW ссылка с примером использования и описанием